# Chartkick y axis uncorrect labeling

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, charts, ruby-on-rails-4

I have chartkick 1.2.0 and groupdate 1.0.4 gem installed. When I try to do sth like:

```
  <%= area_chart Match.group_by_day_of_week(:created_at).count, :width=>"700px;", :height=>"150px;"  %>
```

I get this:

[image]

It always gives me the wrong y-axis. How should I format it so that it would display "Monday", "Tuesday" ...

My second example which I also can't get it right is grouping by hours in a day.

```
  <% abc=Matches.on_location(@location).group_by{|b| b.created_at.strftime("%H").to_i} %>
  <% abc.update(abc){|key, v| v.length} %>
  <%= abc=abc.sort_by{|k,v| k} %>
  <%= area_chart abc, :width=>"700px;", :height=>"150px;"  %>
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong, that it displays 1:00:00 AM etc? I would just like to have numbers ie.: 0, 1, 2, 3 .. 23?

I googled around, checked their docs top to bottom: http://ankane.github.io/chartkick/ for some hours now and I really don't know what have I missed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

[This thread](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/issues/16) on Chartkick's Github indicates that the charting library (Highcharts, in your case?) makes assumptions about what kind of X-axis you want. At a guess, I would say that the issue here is that the library is making an incorrect assumption, so try naming your input's keys in a more obvious format.

In your first example, you could try using the `"Monday"`, `"Tuesday"`, etc as keys instead of `0`, `1`, etc:

```
results = Match.group_by_day_of_week(:created_at).count # hash with numeric keys
days = %w(Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday)
results = results.inject({}){|a, (k,v)| a.update(days[k] => v); a } # change numeric keys to weekday name
```

For the second example, try formatting the date as `%H:%M:%S` so it's more obvious that you want a time axis:

```
abc=Matches.on_location(@location).group_by{|b| b.created_at.strftime("%H:%M:%S")}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the given code also doesn't work. I tried with uppercase lowercase day names, I ordered them by name and gave Sunday on the first place. None of it worked. For your second example I tried if I group them by seconds I would get a gazzilon of key value pairs. I tried but it also doesn't work.

Comment: That's a shame, it was a shot in the dark as I'm not particularly familiar with Chartkick. Perhaps consider opening a thread/filing a bug on their Github so someone who works on the project can take a look and let you know if there's something you need to do, or if it's unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no way to do this right now. As an alternative, you could try a column chart.